# Publish Ansible role to Ansible Galaxy with gitlab-ci

Tags: ansible, gitlab, gitlab-ci, ansible-galaxy

I am developing some Ansible roles and I am using gitlab.com to host my git repositories. 
Because of the simplicity I only want to use Gitlab CI/CD to publish my Ansible roles to Ansible Galaxy.

I found an example in the Ansible Galaxy documentation how to deploy from Travis CI. [Example in the documentation](https://galaxy.ansible.com/docs/contributing/importing.html#import-roles-via-travis-ci)

Is there any solution for that? 
Thank you helping me with my issue.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm also curious.

Comment: Never tried it for galaxy, but should be possible with [webhooks](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html#overview)